# Calculation in paper of learning rate of neural network

Tags: neural-networks

The rate at which a neural network learns something depends on the loss and the backpropagation functions,neural network with different loss and backpropagation functions learn differently at a different rate.However this makes me wonder can we calculate in paper the amount of time or the rate of time at which a neural network learns to do some job given the loss and backpropagation functions?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no.  Deep learning is a thoroughly empirical field.  The main way to know how well something will work is to try it; or to learn from the experience of others who have tried something similar.  In general, there aren't very good rules of thumb or theoretical laws to make predictions about nearly any aspect of neural network performance in practice.  In the specific case of the particular question you raise, there is no way to calculate that.  You will need to experiment to find out.

If someone else has already solved the same problem, you can look to see what they did.  For instance, you can check how many epochs they trained for, and use the same amount.

Or, if no one else has previously done exactly the same thing, if you look at others who have written papers with experiments on similar tasks, you can check to see how many epochs they trained their neural network for, and use that as a guess of how many might be a good thing to try for your task.